# MongoDb giving error while searching

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to get all the documents which has ancestor name as "Laptops" with following lines of code in python with the help of pymongo.

```
for p in collection.find({"ancestors.name":"Laptops"}):
    print p
```

But I am getting this error.

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: database error: BSONObj size: 536871080 (0x200000A8) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: seourl: "https://example.com"
```

If I limit the query as

```
for p in collection.find({"ancestors.name":"Laptops"}).limit(5):
    print p
```

Then it works. So I guess the problem is while fetching all the documents with this category. How to solve this problem? I want all the documents with "Laptops".

**EDIT:-**

With aggregation pipeline Concept I tried following query

```
db.product_attributes.aggregate([
{
    $match:
    {
        "ancestors.name":"Laptops"
    }
    }
])
```

I get the same error

```
uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: BSONObj size: 536871080 (0x200000A8) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: seourl: \"https://example.com"",
    "code" : 10334,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

Whats wrong here..? Help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

The maximum size of a document returned by the query is 16MB.  You can see that, and other limits on the [official document](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/)

To overcome this you could count the total number of records and loop over the records and print them

**Sample:**

```
count=db.collection.count({"ancestors.name":"Laptops"})
for num in range (0,count,500):
     if num!=0:
         for p in collection.find({"ancestors.name":"Laptops"}).skip(num-1).limit(500):
              print p
      else:
         for p in collection.find({"ancestors.name":"Laptops"}).limit(500):
              print p
```

**Warning:**

This method is slow since you skip and limit records

Comment: @Gunjan did you try changing the limit to something less like 100

Comment: Yes I did to 10. But still the same issue.

Comment: @Gunjan could you post the complete traceback

Comment: @Gunjan the statement says you are still using `for p in self.collection.find({"ancestors.name":category}):` instaed of limit

Comment: sorry for that..I had added old traceback..but thats the pretty much error I am getting..so I updated it to before.

Comment: @Gunjan are you getting this error even when you try for limit as 2

Answer (score 1):

The restriction was created to not allow your mongoDB process to consume **all your memory** on server.To know more - here is a [ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-431) about 4->16 MB limit increase, and discussion about it purpose.

Alternative approach is to use [Aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/)

> If the aggregate command returns a single document that contains the
>   complete result set, the command will produce an error if the result
>   set exceeds the BSON Document Size limit, which is currently 16
>   megabytes. To manage result sets that exceed this limit, the aggregate
>   command can return result sets of any size if the command return a
>   cursor or store the results to a collection.

Comment: Tried this query "db.product_attributes.aggregate([{"$match":{"ancestors.name":"Laptops"}}])". Still getting the same error